# Http Error 12031 when calling a Web Service Method in Web Farm Environment

Tags: asp.net-ajax, iis-6, web-services, web-farm

Currently we have an ASP.NET application running on 3 web servers (in a webfarm).
We have an ASMX Webservice with ScriptService enabled, and we used it with ScriptManager in some of our ASPX pages and invoked some methods using javascript (with Microsoft Ajax Framework).

Our problem is that when more than 1 servers are running, some Ajax Call to the asmx service  will return Http Error 12031(Connection to the server has been reset).

We cannot replicate the issue if only 1 server is running. 
Is this an application related or IIS perhaps?
We find no clues for this, Please help.

Your thoughts are very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using in process or out of process session state?

Comment: We are your using in process session state.